# How to set an imap account without local pst storage in outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, imap, pst

This is my issue: I have 20 people sharing a Terminal Server, and they want to use MS Outlook 2010 to access their IMAP folders. Some are Gmail acocunts with over 10 Gb of emails. Some people use the same account, so I have lots of duplicates and a lot of wasted (and precious) storage.

This is my question. Is it possible to set an IMAP account in Outlook without having it to copy all the data to the .pst file? Or is it possible to limit the .pst to a fixed size (eg: 1 Gb) in order to cache just the last emails locally and retrieve the older directly from IMAP?

I've tried to limit the size by regedit but doesn't seem working the way I want.

Any solution/suggestion is welcome, all I want is that Outlook work with IMAP accounts whitout caching all the IMAP data locally on those big (and horribly performing) .pst craps.

Comment: .PST isn't used by the IMAP its only created if the user chooses to create it.

Comment: so how can I create an IMAP account on Outlook without having a .PST file?

Comment: Again; By default the .PST isn't created until the user creates it.  If you don't want a .PST to exist just delete it.

Comment: By using IMAP accounts (not on an Exchange Server) is not possible to avoid .PST files 'cause Outlook needs to create it. I'll make them switch to another client to solve this problem. thanks for info btw.